# Starting resque workers while started development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

I want to start my workers when I start my development server to test the a new cron job I have in my resque scheduler, so I run this command when starting dev server-

```
QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work rails s
```

it has worked for me before and if I'm [reading their documentation correctly](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-ensure-my-rails-classesenvironment-is-loaded) should still work.

But I'm getting the following error after I interrupt it after it gets hung up-

```
^Crake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails'
```

here is what I get after keyboard interrupt and running it with `--trace`

```
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke resque:work (first_time)
** Invoke resque:preload (first_time)
** Invoke resque:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute resque:setup
** Execute resque:preload
** Invoke resque:setup
** Execute resque:work
^Crake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'rails'
```

I don't understand why I would be getting the error and additionally why it previously loaded and worked but not anymore. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure that you manage to run this command sometime back successfully

`QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work rails s`

because the way I know `rails s` is a list of rails command not a rake task

you can run consecutive rake separating spaces like

`QUEUE=* rake environment rake1 rake2 rake3`

but you **cant run** a rake and rails command they way you mention above

what I see from your trace above that rake(**resque rake**) is running now instead of passing a second rake you specified a **rails command** to start the server rake is considering that as rake task (which is not true)

I believe you are looking for this

`QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work && rails s`

But I dont believe that what you have mention would ever work please let me know if something conflict over here

Hope It make sense

Comment: yes this makes perfect sense, thanks for breaking it down, and it must not have been the case that I previously ran that command with success. Sorry for the misinformation and thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 4):

This is better:

```
BACKGROUND=yes QUEUE=* PIDFILE=./tmp/resque.pid bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

Then:

```
rails s
```

If you need stop resque worker:

```
kill -QUIT $(cat ./tmp/resque.pid)
```